# Is there a way to write over a unicode character?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to write a number on top of the unicode character '♤' on a website. I know i could just make images and use those but since i'll have more than 200 ♤ symbols with unique number i would prefer not to use the images since they would take up a lot of space.

So the size of the characters would have to be different. The space with the number would go inside a div tag. I really hope there is a way to do this, otherwise ill settle for the images.

Comment: `position: absolute` lets you overlap html elements...

Comment: :before or :after have you tried? please write  your code here I will give you an example then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.heart > div:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
}
.heart > div:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: -42px;
  left: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
  <div>♤</div>
  <div>A</div>
</div>
```